# Как сделать так чтобы при вставке имени, в БД записывалось id этого имени?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблицы:

```
stations (st_id integer, st_name); 
routes(route_id, start_st_id integer, end_st_id integer);
```

Где `routes.start_st_id` и `routes.end_st_id` привязаны к `stations.st_id`.

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я хочу добавить новый маршрут (`routes`) в БД, например:

```
'Москва', 'Санкт-петербург'
```

в `routes` записывались `id` этих имен?

Comment: Вам надо сделать view, которая путем join будет выдавать таблицу так, как будто в ней имена. После этого написать на эту view "instead of trigger", который собственно будет получать по именам id и вставлять их в таблицу

Comment: благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для приведённых в вопросе данных, можно сделать вставку из запроса:

```sql
create table stations as 
    select rownum st_id, trim (column_value) st_name
    from xmlTable ('"Москва", "Санкт-Петербург"'); 

create table routes (route_id number generated always as identity, start_st_id integer, end_st_id integer);

insert into routes (start_st_id, end_st_id)  
    select sp.st_id, ep.st_id
    from stations sp
    cross join stations ep
    where sp.st_name = 'Москва' and ep.st_name = 'Санкт-Петербург'
;    
select * from routes;
```

Вывод:

```
  ROUTE_ID START_ST_ID  END_ST_ID
---------- ----------- ----------
         1           1          2
```