# Как написать триггер на вставку записи вo View?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер

Kак написать триггер, чтобы при вставке во View записывались `id` имен в таблицу под именем `routes`?

```
CREATE TABLE stations
    (st_id int,
    st_name varchar2(25));

CREATE SEQUENCE st_id_seq
START WITH 1
NOCACHE;

INSERT INTO stations
VALUES (st_id_seq.nextval, 'Moscow');

INSERT INTO stations
VALUES (st_id_seq.nextval, 'St. Petersburg');

CREATE TABLE routes
    (route_id int,
    start_st_id int,
    end_st_id int);

CREATE VIEW routes_vw AS
SELECT r.route_id, s1.st_name, start_station s2.st_name end_station
FROM routes r
JOIN stations s1 ON (s1.st_id = r.start_st_id)
JOIN stations s2 ON (s2.st_id = r.end_st_id);

SELECT *
FROM routes_vw
```

А что должно быть в блоке триггера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER routes_vw_trg 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
ON routes_vw 
BEGIN

END;
```

Не могли бы помочь?

Comment: Посмотрите, я в [похожей теме дал ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1039157/217579), он вам поможет разобраться с вашей задачей?

Comment: Хотя, ваша задача вытекает, по видимому, из вашего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1039107/217579). Там я вам уже ответил, что нет никакой необходимости создавать триггер.

Comment: Да, но в том коде который вы мне написали, я же не могу вставить много маршрутов или могу? Просто я новичек не совсем понял. А на счет триггера я понял, но создавть что то не получается

Comment: Почему нет? Сколько маршрутов вернёт подапрос, столько и вставится. Если бы вы добавили в вопрос пример данных, то я бы показал с ними.

Comment: спасибо большое) я вас понял, разобрался

Comment: Рад был помочь! Только учтите, cross join  здесь и в другом вопросе подходит только для вами преведённых данных. Например добавится в stations колонка путь (track), то будут вставлены все возможные маршруты от любого пути станции отпровления до любого пути станции прибытия. Если это не ожидается, то вам надо будет доработать подзапрос.

Comment: Хорошо, колонки track не будет, но знать буду

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```sql
create or replace trigger routes_vw_trg 
instead of insert on routes_vw 
begin
    if (:new.start_station is not null and :new.end_station is not null) then
        insert into routes  
            select :new.route_id, sp.st_id, ep.st_id 
            from stations sp
            cross join stations ep
            where sp.st_name = :new.start_station and ep.st_name = :new.end_station
        ;
    else raise_application_error (-20000, 'cannot insert null values');
    end if;        
end;
/
insert into routes_vw values (1, 'Moscow', 'St. Petersburg');
```

Результат как и ожидалось:

```sql
select * from routes_vw;

  ROUTE_ID START_STATION             END_STATION              
---------- ------------------------- -------------------------
         1 Moscow                    St. Petersburg
```